# system call in perl script return -1 when running with puppet

Tags: perl, puppet

I have a third party perl script that I need to run with puppet. In the script there are some commands to create the directories using the following perl statements:

```
system("mkdir -p /tmp/agent") && die "failed to create agent dir";
```

I can manually run the script without any problem using root user. However, when I run the script with puppet:

```
exec {'install agent':
    command => "perl /tmp/install_agent.pl",
    creates => '/tmp/agent/agent',
    path => '/usr/bin',
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: perl /tmp/install_agent.pl returned 2 instead of one of [0]
```

When I try to capture the return value of the system call, I got -1. With more testing, It seems all the system call failed with -1.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Is Perl running in taint mode? Check `${^TAINT}`, documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). More on tain mode in [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html).

Comment: Take a look at `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}` in your `die` statement for the return value of the child call.

Comment: Alternately, change the `system()` call into a native call to `mkdir()` and then if you have any failures you can look at `$!` for more info.

Comment: ${^TAINT} = 0 and ${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE} = -1

Comment: And mkdir() return 1 and the directory created successfully....

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect /tmp/install_agent.pl doesn't exist when the exec runs.  Just as a test I ran 'perl /nonexistant.file' and the return code was 2.

Watever resource you have creating the file needs to run first.  So if it's a file resource:

```
file {'/tmp/install_agent':
  ensure => file,
  content => 'system("mkdir -p /tmp/agent") && die "failed to create agent dir";'
}

exec {'install agent':
    command => "perl /tmp/install_agent.pl",
    creates => '/tmp/agent/agent',
    path => '/usr/bin',
    require => File['/tmp/install_agent.pl'],
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the install_agent.pl is exists as the statments before "system("mkdir -p /tmp/agent")" got executed and extracted some files.